# Cannot remove project name from the form action in Cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to Cakephp 3.0 i have created a form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Login', array('url' => array('controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'dashboard'))); ?>
<label for="login-username">username</label>
<?= $this->Form->input('username'); ?>
<label for="login-password">password</label>
<?= $this->Form->input('password', array('type'=>'password')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->submit('Login',array('class' => 'button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I have to redirect it to Login controller and dashboard action, but in inspect element i can see /stock_mgmt_system/login/dashboard where stock_mgmt_system is the project name.

Please try to solve my issue.

Comment: so what is the problem ? that looks all good.

Answer (score 0):

Did you named your controller LoginsController respecting cake convention ?

If yes just replace "login" with "logins" in "controller" just like that

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, [
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Logins', 'action' => 'dashboard']
]);
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/fr/views/helpers/form.html